# How to update Polygon shapefile attributes using point shapefile attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a large number of polygon shapefile and a point shapefile. Each polygon has only one point over it with updated attributes. The field names in the attribute table are same for both shapefile. How to update polygon attributes using point attributes in ArcGIS?

Comment: There are a number of ways  to accomplish your goal, including a spatial join, Intersect/Union, and a Python script. Please do some initial research before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

**Spatial Join** the points to the polygons.

The tool will create a new dataset of polygons that will now have all of the points' attribute data within each polygon's row in the attribute table. It won't overwrite your input data fortunately.